# Set font awesome icon into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am ussing html, css3 and jquery. And i want to use font awesome icon into jquery. But i don't know how to use font awesome icon into Jquery.

FONT ICON:

```
<i  class="fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw "></i>
```

CODE:

```
<div class="display-icon">
     <i  class="fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw "></i>
</div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$('.display-icon').click(function(){
-----FONT AWESOME ICON------
});
```

Font awesome icon working fine in the html code.
I want to set this icon into jquery code.

Comment: Either you can add the the icon to a div and set display property as none to it. And Whenever you want it you can show it from JQuery. Or from jquery : $('#your_div_id').html("<i class='fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw'></i>"); Both will work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by setting the icon?

Comment: I want to put this icon from jquery same as your first comment(code). It is not working.

Comment: Can you share the code ?

Comment: Without the Jquery, Is it coming if you directly put it inside the div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution, I would suggest targeting with `<i id="myId">` instead of the *children* of "display icon", more tighter...

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="display-icon">
    <i class="fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw "></i>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
    $('.display-icon').click(function() {
      $(this).children("i").attr("class", "fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw ") ;
    });  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks save my time thanks a lot. If you like my question use full for others then voting up. Thanks again your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $('.display-icon').click(function(){
    $("#show-icon").addClass('fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw ');
});
```

and:

```
    <div class="display-icon">
    click me :)
    <i  class="" id="show-icon"></i>
</div>
```

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: If you like my question then voting up helps to others and for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a spinner icon when button is clicked, you may insert at the desired place in the HTML and toggle visibility with javascript (jQuery in your case):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle-spinner').on('click', function(){
        $('#my-spinner').toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="toggle-spinner" value="Toggle spinner"/>
<div id="my-spinner" class="display-icon" style="display: none"> <i class="fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw "></i> </div>
```

You may also add and remove an HTML element in DOM:

```
$(' <div id="my-spinner" class="display-icon"> <i class="fa-spinnerZoom fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw "></i> </div> ').appendTo('body');

$('#my-spinner').remove();
```